# Fetching the revelvant node based upon the tags attched to current node

Tags: 7, nodes

I have a requirement to fetch the 5 relevant nodes based upon the taxonomy tags attached to the current node. Relevant nodes has to be fetched based upon the following logic.

> 1) If current node has 4 tags, first need to check whether we have 5
>   nodes with all matching tags. Then list all nodes.
>
> 2) If we don't have 5 nodes with 4 matching tags , then need to look
>   into 3 matching tags. If we got 5 nodes with 4 and 3 matching tags
>   list the nodes else again look for 2 matching tags and so on.

I am planing to write a module for this. But unable to find a proper solution for this problem. Any help is greatly appreciated .

Comment: How much accuracy is important for you? I do have an idea , it is greedy , fast and returns value much faster but it can has errors , I mean there might be more relevant content which might be bypassed

Comment: @AlirezaTabatabaeian at least 95% accuracy is fine for me